# How to update a fragment which starts an activity?

Tags: android-fragments, android-activity

I have a fragment A. There is a button in A which starts an activity named B.  Is there any way I can actually make some changes in the fragment A once the activity B has been finished?  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can startActivityForResult from Activity that is a parent to your Fragment A. You have to put a requestCode. Let's say:

```
val requestCode = 1
```

Then add setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK) to OnDestroy() of your Activity B.

The OnDestroy() should look something like this:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

Finally add this to your fragment:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == requestCode)
            // make some changes
            // you can also add a check to see if resultCode equals Result.OK
    }
```

This will activate when Activity B is finished.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Many Thanks to you. It works for me. Although, instead of using  Activity’s startActivityForResult(…)method, I use Fragment.startActivityForResult(…) and instead of overriding Activity.onActivityResult(…), I override Fragment.onActivityResult(…).